# Can public static class name variable be called without object

Tags: java, oop, static

```
public class StateCacheManager {
    public static StateCacheManager mInstance;
}
```

My question is can the variable `mInstance` be called without object? If no then what is the significance of above statement?

Answer (score 0):

The `static` keyword identifies elements of the class that can be accessed without constructing an instance. You can access them using the class name as a qualifier.

In this case you can write `StateCacheManager.mInstance`

Answer (score 0):

`mInstance` is an object of the class `StateCacheManager`. There will only be a single object of this class.

There should be a `getInstance` method below that initializes `mInstance`.

```
public class StateCacheManager {
    public static StateCacheManager mInstance;

    public StateCacheManager getInstance(){
        if(mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new StateCacheManager();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

This is how you use it,

```
StateCacheManager object = StateCacheManager.getInstance();
```

This class uses a pattern called [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

If something (a method, a field, an inner class etc) is modified with `static`, it can be accessed using its name, with a `ClassName.` suffix.

So your `mInstance` variable can be accessed like this:

```
StateCacheManager.mInstance
```

As you can see, I did not create any object to access it, so the answer to your first question is "Yes".

However, you should probably make the `mInstance` variable `private` and add a getter:

```
public static StateCacheManager mInstance = new StateCacheManager();
public StateCacheManager getInstance() { return mInstance; }
```

This is to prevent other users of your code, or a sleepy you, from accidentally setting `mInstance` to something else which you don't want.

This is called the *Singleton Pattern*. It is used when you only want one instance of a class to exist.